# CloudFlare keeps deleting my DNS Records from Amazon SES

Tags: email, dns, cloudflare, amazon-ses, dkim

I have a website hosted on Hostgator but i use CloudFlare (free) for caching and SSL.

I am trying to make marketing automation with Amazon SES but CloudFlare keeps deleting my DNS Records from aws.

In manage identities in AWS Console for SES there is 4 things to put on the server DNS. A txt  and other 3 TXT for DKIM.. I put that in cloudflare and it works for some days till Cloudflare delete everything and Amazon complains sending me an email.

Its the 4th time that this happens, how can i make them don't delete my stuff?

Also, i tried to keep this records in my hostgator account since there is A records with my host ip, but this didn't worked.

Comment: Who is your DNS provider?  If you're using CloudFlare the records should be in CloudFlares configuration, if they're removing your records this is not part of a standard process and should be raised with them I would suggest :)

Comment: I tried.. no response.. Why would someone vote down my question without saying even why? People don't make sense..

Comment: Hmm not sure on that one, this to me sounds like a CloudFlare issue :(

Comment: :/ ill try them again.. but without paying the support is pretty bad

Comment: If this is a serious issue,  which it sounds like,  consider tweeting to Cloudflare about the the problem: https://twitter.com/Cloudflare

Comment: Regarding downvoting your question,  it does not make sense.  Probably downvoting should be guarded by a comment because with current impl it does not help the OP at all.

Comment: Hmm ill try the twitter! Good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have another DNS provider in between them?

I used Ezoic and had the same problem.. They were deleting my CloudFlare DNS records. But when i put them on Ezoic eveything worked fine!

Maybe you have something like that and they will be reflected on CloudFlare by the other provider.